# Redirecionamento de página conforme país de acesso

Tags: php, redirecionamento

Possuo 2 páginas PHP, uma em português e a outra em inglês, e gostaria que o usuário fosse redirecionado automaticamente para a inglês, caso o acesso fosse fora do Brasil. Existe alguma maneira ? Ou a solução mas eficaz é criar um link para a página em inglês, igual possui em muitos sites.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553160/getting-visitors-country-from-their-ip

Comment: Você pode redirecionar a página caso o IP do usuário não comece com 200... é o primeiro número do IP brasileiro.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]](http://php.net/reserved.variables.server) do php. Ela traz informações enviadas do browser.

```
<?php
 echo $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
 // pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,gl;q=0.2

$arralang = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
$lang = $arrlang[0];

switch ($lang) {
    case 'pt-BR':
      // redireciona para página em português
      break;
    case 'en-US':
    case 'en':
      // redireciona para página em inglês
      break;
    default:
      // redireciona para página em português
 }
```

Comment: há um problema com isso, eu estou em portugal, no entanto depois de testar deu-me "en-US"

Comment: Interessante Miguel!!! Fiz uma pesquisa rápida. Parece que o Firefox dá preferência à "en-US". Me confirme qual foi o navegador que você usou e, se possível, teste em outro navegador para termos mais dados.

Comment: Sim foi esse mesmo, mas não consigo testar noutro porque de momento o chrome está-me a crashar

Answer (score 1):

Dependendo da tua versão do PHP, dê uma lida na documentação do PHP sobre [Classe de localização](http://php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php)

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar uma API, neste caso usei http://ip-api.com/, e fazer:

```
// descobrir o ip do utilizador
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$ip_test = '97.162.48.46';
$local_json = @file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/' .$ip_test); // aqui usa o $ip, este é só para teste

$countries_en = array('gb', 'us'); // definir codigo iso2 dos paises para os quais o site será apresentado em inglês
$lang = 'pt'; // linguagem default
if($local_json !== false) {
    $local_array = json_decode($local_json, true);
    if($local_array !== null && isset($local_array['countryCode'])) {
        if(in_array(strtolower($local_array['countryCode']), $countries_en)) {
            $lang = 'en'; // definir site com a linguagem Inglês
        }
    }
}
echo $lang; // en, pois o país (neste exemplo) são os EUA, cujo código é US, está dentro do nosso array $countries_en
```

Note que no servidor de produção em vez de `$ip_test` usa o `$ip`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar também esta alternativa, redirecionando para default ou a linguagem, caso exista.

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']; // pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,gl;q=0.2     

$arrlang = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
$lang = $arrlang[0];
$default_lang = "pt-br";

if(isset($lang)){
     header("Location: url/".$lang);
} else {
     header("Location: url/".$default_lang);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de fazer isso, é usando uma API, que identifique o país, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
function isBrazil() {
    $location = file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/');
    if ($location) {
       $data = json_decode($location, true);
       if ($data['country_name'] == 'Brazil') {
          return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}

if (isBrazil()) {
   header('Location: pagina-brasil.php');
} else {
   header('Location: pagina-ingles.php');
}
```

Ou se quiser só redirecionar para fora...

```
 if (!isBrazil()) {
    header('Location: pagina-ingles.php');
 }
```